# How to stop aws sync process using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, amazon-s3, cmd, aws-cli

I am write aws s3 data backup inside batch file as bellow

test.bat

```
@echo off

echo ---------Data synchronization START at %date% %time%------------  

:loop
    aws s3 sync D:\backup s3://upload --exclude "*.jpg"


IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :loop
echo ---------Data synchronization END at %date% %time%------------
```

this batch file run using run.bat file that look like bellow

run.bat

```
@echo off
start  test.bat
timeout /t 10
taskkill /fi "imagename eq aws.exe" /f
taskkill /fi  test.bat /f
```

I want to stop aws sync and close test.bat window after 10s run `test.bat` file 
i try to stop aws sync process using `taskkill /fi "imagename eq aws.exe" /f`
and close test.bat window using `taskkill /fi  test.bat /f`

but i can't stop aws sync process and close `test.bat` window

Comment: Why do you want to kill aws and the batch? this line `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :loop` is not supposed to end the loop after the sync is finished? have you tried to kill first test.bat ?

Comment: yes i try but i can't kill test.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add title to test.bat then taskill with the filter of windowtitle

```
@echo off
setlocal
title test.bat
echo ---------Data synchronization START at %date% %time%------------  
for /L %%i in (1,1,1000)
aws s3 sync D:\backup s3://upload --exclude "*.jpg"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :loop
echo ---------Data synchronization END at %date% %time%------------  
exit /b 0
```

run.bat

```
@echo off
start "" test.bat
timeout /t 10 >nul
taskkill /f /im cmd.exe /fi "windowtitle eq test.bat"
taskkill /f /im aws.exe /fi "imagename eq aws.exe"
```

you could also add a `stop.tmp` after `timeout` and check if file exist and then `exit /b 0`

```
@echo off
setlocal
title test.bat
echo ---------Data synchronization START at %date% %time%------------  
for /L %%i in (1,1,1000)
aws s3 sync D:\backup s3://upload --exclude "*.jpg"

IF EXIST stop.tmp del stop.tmp &exit /b 0
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO :loop
echo ---------Data synchronization END at %date% %time%------------  
exit /b 0
```

run.bat with stop.tmp

```
@echo off
start "" test.bat
timeout /t 10 >nul
copy nul stop.tmp
```

Comment: test.bat window doesn't close